# Merge commits where all parents are from the same branch are not allowed

Tags: git, version-control, github, merge, git-branch

I am having 3 branches i.e, `develop, feature, xyz`. Right now I am working in `xyz` branch and commit here. Then i have followed these steps

```
git checkout feature
git merge xyz
```

-- Here it copied that commit and created one more commit as "merge: prev_commit latest_commit". So in `feature` i have 2 new commits means non pushed commits.

```
git checkout develop
git merge xyz
```

-- here also it does the same thing. It copied that commit and created one more commit as "merge: prev_commit latest_commit". So in `feature` i have 2 new commits means non pushed commits.

So I have tried to push my changes to the server. Both `xyz`, `feature` branches are pushing properly. But `develop` branch is not able to push the updated commits and showing error as follows.

```
"remote: Merge commits where all parents are from the same branch are not allowed."
```

Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually this limitation isn't a git standard one. So I think the upstream server that you use has its own constraints regarding commits being pushed. Likely you should consult w/ repository owners/administrators

Comment: Is it possible to see the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate develop xyz feature`?

Answer (score 4):

I strongly suspect you are running into the remote repository's defense mechanism against a common Git problem: nuisance merges.

Many users of Git prefer to keep a linear, or mostly linear history free of distracting, nuisance "mini merges" that are caused by developers doing a `git pull --merge` instead of a `git pull --rebase` when integrating upstream changes with their local work.  It sounds as if your remote repo may have a defensive check against this common problem.

Possibly, the restriction is branch-specific: on `feature` you were allowed to get away with it, but not on `develop`.

Further hypothesizing, it's possible that your genuine branch merge is being mistaken for a nuisance merge because the remote repository either doesn't know about the `xyz` branch, or the `xyz` branch on the remote end was out of date with respect to the local `xyz` work at the time you pushed the merge.

In other words, the second parent of the merge on `develop` has a SHA which does not correspond to any branch on the remote end. Perhaps the remote runs something like `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref <SHA>` on that parent, and it comes out blank.

Though you say that `xyz` is pushing properly, the order matters: `xyz` has to be pushed first so the branch is up-to-date on the remote, and the remote can then understand that the second merge parent is referring to `xyz`.

If `xyz` is completely up-to-date, and yet the `develop` push is being rejected, that suggests that the logic on the remote is buggy.

(There is one more possibility and that is that `xyz` is not behind, but rather ahead, on the remote. If merge an out-of-date local `xyz` to `develop` and push, that hash does not correspond to the current `xyz` on remote. That hash points into the middle of `xyz` somewhere.)

Comment: Paranoic, i also am wasting time for my job because of nonsense, theoric-only limitations.
I checked out a branch, somebody did a push before I did another pull. I did pull, solved conflicts, and when i try to push, here is the problem.
So: I will clone a fresh copy of the repo and copy-paste changes again, because the time goes on and doesn't wait for me.